# Can Quorum be run on RHEL?

Tags: quorum

Understand Quorum examples are running on Ubuntu -- Is Quorum able to run on top of RHEL OS?

Comment: Yes, you need to install Go and Constellation dependencies.

Comment: thanks! answer came too late though... i have built, install and setup a full fledge solution already on RHEL. First in the world!